# Why is parameter sometimes null by JSF Parameter passing?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, codi

I pass the managedbean that i use (myBean) as parameter to another managedbean(PersonRoleSearch) so that I can call the methods of the first bean (myBean). But sometimes the parameter is null, therefore i get nullpointer exception. There is no explanation for me why it occurs.

```
<a4j:commandLink id="PersonSearch" styleClass="no-decor"
                        status="noAjaxStatus" execute="@searchGemOrderGroup"
                        immediate="true"
                        oncomplete="#{rich:component('personRoleSearchPopupPanel')}.show()"
                        action="#{personRoleSearch.doInit(myBean)}"
                        render="personRoleSearchPopupPanel">
                        <h:graphicImage value="/resources/icons/blue/searchperson.png"
                            alt="#{msg['personSearch.search']}" />
                    </a4j:commandLink>
```

Hier ist the init method of Personrolesearch

```
 public void doInit(final MyBean target){...}

 public void doSomething(){
   target.myBeanMethod();

    ...}
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: Probably wrong scope of the bean. Look up CDI, you don't have to pass beans around as parameters.

Comment: @Makhiel But it works 98%. Only sometimes it is the case. How can you explain it?

Comment: @Makhiel How can I call the methods without injection?

Comment: @BalusC How can i prevent this case?

Comment: @BalusC it is in that case very difficult to find the optimum code part. I dont know what you need exactly. And as i said before it is very difficult to reproduce. There is no guarantee if it fails or not. it works  %98. But the button can be clicked if only the page is visible. It means the managedbean should be there..

Comment: @BalusC Yes we use `@ViewAccessScoped` for the managedbeans